# Change URL for Blog?

Tags: url-rewriting

Using WP 3.1.1 as a CMS, using the [Boldy](http://www.site5.com/wordpress-themes/) theme.
Home page is at http://www.dekho.com.au

Advantage of using this theme, is that it comes setup with a homepage that has a gallery slider and some homeboxes at the bottom.

To get to the blog, I had to dump all my posts into a category called blog.
- The themes docco advises to do this][3](http://www.dekho.com.au/category/blog/).
I can then link to this blog category from the top menu.

This then passes me to this URL:
[http://www.dekho.com.au/?category_name=blog](http://www.dekho.com.au/category/blog/)

**I want to know how to retain the home page provided by Boldy, but have the blog on a separate page with the following URL:**
*dekho.com.au/blog*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to change your Front Page settings:

1) Create a *Static Page*, called "Blog" (and a slug of "blog")

2) Create another *Static Page*, to serve as your site Front Page

3) Go to Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading

4) Change "Front Page Displays" from "Your latest posts" to "A static Page (select below)"

5) In the "Front Page" dropdown, select the Static Page that you created to serve as your site Front Page

6) In the "Posts Page" dropdown, select the Static Page "Blog"

Next, you need to fix your permalinks:

1) Go to Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks

2) Select one of the default options ("Month and Name" is usually good)

3) Save settings, to write the rewrite rules to .htaccess

Now dekho.com.au/blog should be displaying your blog posts index

Comment: This sounds like the correct answer, but perhaps not for my Boldy theme? http://wordpress.site5.net/boldy/doc/
I have not actually created a page for the home page, a homepage is built into it.
I created a static page called blog
If I choose FP displays static page, leave front page blank and choose blog for posts = does not work.  If I choose a different page for front page, I lose my original homepage with image slider.

Comment: Boldy does it wrong. It uses the `home.php` template file (which is intended to be used for the *blog posts index*) for its custom Front Page, when it should be using `front-page.php` (which is intended *always* to be used for the site Front Page, whether displaying the blog posts index or a static Page). The simplest solution would be to rename `home.php` as `front-page.php`.

Comment: This would likely have a knock on effect elsewhere?  I will have to do some testing on a dev box.

Comment: It shouldn't have any ill effects. The blog posts index will revert to using the `index.php` template file, and your Front Page will be using the `front-page.php` template file, as desired.

Comment: Renamed home.php to front-page php
Bit confused with your steps 2 & 4
If I create a dummy page for my front page, how can I get it to look the same as the boldy front page with the gallery slider and home boxes?

Comment: Think of it more as a *placeholder* than a "dummy page". When you assign that Page as the Front Page, WordPress automatically uses the correct template file, i.e. `front-page.php`.

Comment: Only Side affect, is that on the home page: http://www.dekho.com.au/  
If you look, there is a line running down the background.

Any idea on how to remove this?

Comment: Look in your [style.css](http://www.dekho.com.au/wordpress/wp-content/themes/boldy/style.css) file, for `#content`. The vertical line is caused by the `background:url(images/bk_vertline.jpg) 695px 0 repeat-y;` property of the `#content` declaration.

Comment: p.s. I found that by using Chrome Developer Tools, which is indispensable if you use the Chrome browser. If you use Firefox, try the Firebug extension.

Comment: Works but 2 Side affects:
On the home page: http://www.dekho.com.au/  
If you look, there is a line running down the background.
- its using different page template for background.

IF you also look at blog page - http://www.dekho.com.au/blog/
It has the reverse.  Background line is horizontal as opposed to vertical along the right sidebar.  Any idea on how to adjust this and then im done? :)

Comment: I cant remove it from my styles, as its required for the other pages.

Comment: Your blog page is using this CSS declaration: `body#home #mainWrapper {
 background:url(images/bk_main_wrapper_home.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
}`.

Comment: Basically, you need to swap these two CSS background declarations (`#content` and `body#home #mainWrapper`), and everything *should* be working fine.

Comment: You could also create your own `home.php` template file, to control the output/style of your blog posts index? To give more specific help, I'd have to dig through Boldy's template files and style.css, to see what all is going on.

Comment: "swap these two CSS background declarations"
Just tried that and did not work. 
IF it helps...
http://www.dekho.com.au/front-page_delete.txt,
http://dekho.com.au/wordpress/wp-content/themes/boldy/style.css

Comment: Look in `header.php`, and find this: `<body <?php if(is_home()){`. Change the `is_home()` conditional to `is_front_page()`, and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Yes, that seems to have fixed it.
If you come wash my dishes, ill answer this as solved :)
(Thanks loads)

Comment: Ha! I've got my own dishes to wash. :)