# Hide Category from Blog?

Tags: categories

I am using the [Boldy theme](http://wordpress.site5.net/boldy/doc/) from Site5 on a [v3.1.2 site](http://www.dekho.com.au).

The way this theme works, is that there is a portfolio, (which I am using as a [case studies gallery](http://www.dekho.com.au/category/case-studies/)) that pulls in posts from a specific category you define under the themes settings *(id=98)*

This is fine if you also set the blog up as per the Boldy instructions, where all blog posts come under a category called blog, but this wasnn't going to give me the slugs I wanted, so [I adopted to use a static page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/change-url-for-blog) called blog to show my posts on.

This all works fine, apart from the fact that the posts I create for my portfolio/case studies gallery (category = case studies) now appear in my blog as well.

Is there a way to hide posts within a specific category within the blog, but for it not to have the same affect in my case studies gallery?

**--EDIT--**
With some help from Wyck via the comments, made *some* progress.
[Here is a txt version](http://www.dekho.com.au/index.txt) of my themes default index.php file.

If I insert the following onto Line 2:

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-98'); ?>
```

= This results in no posts being shown on my [Downloads](http://www.dekho.com.au/category/case-studies/) page, but all posts still appearing on my [Blog](http://www.dekho.com.au/blog/) page.

I need the vice versa of this.  I am sure I am close, but perhaps I need to modify which line I put this on?

**--EDIT x2--**
Now using the download monitor for my downloads gallery.  But using the portfolio for my case studies.  So some of the links above have changed, but the problem is exactly the same.

Comment: So you don't want downloads to appear on your main blog -- is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  In the long run, ill be also using the portfolio for a 'case studies' page.  Therefore ill also need to exclude case study posts from the blog page.

Comment: what you want can be achieved by modifying the query to exclude a particular category but I am not sure of the code to modify it, it will probably be 4-5 lines

Comment: ok I think I have got it working, will post an answer soon. I need to study your question what behavior do you exactly want it to do on various pages.

Comment: @simon Take a look at my answer and let me know if it does what you want

Comment: @Ashfame, thats the bit that im struggling with. Which lines in index.php to change.

Comment: @Simon, you don't need to change anything, just paste my code in `functions.php` file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the category 98 to be excluded only on the blog page, right? They should be accessible on the category page directly (your downloads page), correct?

Can you try this? Let me know if its not what you want, we can modify it to suit your needs. Right not it only excludes the category on where you show your blog posts.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'block_cat_query' );

function block_cat_query() {
    global $wp_query;   
    if( is_home() ) {
        $wp_query->query_vars['cat'] = '-98';
    }
}
```

Comment: This has worked!  Im going to hold off marking this as an answer until ive done some full testing.  Thanks loads Ashfame.

Comment: Great! As a test checkout the different pages where you want those particular posts to be shown or not to be shown and let me know :)

Comment: @Simon Great! You didn't even bother to take a few secs to award the bounty.

Comment: I thought marking the anser as resolved awarded u the bounty?

Comment: Sorry man, ive flagged for a moderator to re-direct the bounty to you.  Its first time ive made use of the bounty feature.  I figured it went to the one I marked as the answer

Comment: @Simon sorry, but it's not in moderator powers to move the bounty.

Comment: @Simon Never mind! It was my first answer to a question with bounty too.

Comment: So sorry Ashfame.  I owe u one.  Have learnt a lesson here.  Let me know if you ever have any mapping related questions.  Have good weekend

Answer (score 3):

In Settings -> Reading if your Front Page is not set to show "Latest Posts" whatever is selected as posts page will use the index.php template.

> I do use a static page, but I think it
> still uses index.php to populate items
> on this static page? I checked by
> fiddling some free text in index.php
> and it was reflected in the blog posts
> on the static page. – Simon 4 hours
> ago

Your comment is correct your "static page" is using index.php

To use a static page with a custom template for your blog post change your reading settings as follows:

#### Change This:

[image]

#### To This:

[image]

For your custom template <del>just copy and paste index.php to</del> create a new file and name it custom-page-blog.php and add this to it.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
    get_header();
    
            $args=array(
                'category__not_in' => 98
                );
                $blog_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                            
             while ($blog_query->have_posts()) : $blog_query->the_post(); ?>        
            
            <!-- Begin .postBox -->
            <div class="postItem">
            
                    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1> 
                    <div class="meta">
                                <?php the_time('M j, Y') ?> &nbsp;&nbsp;//&nbsp;&nbsp; by <span class="author"><?php the_author_link(); ?></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;//&nbsp;&nbsp;  <?php the_category(', ') ?>  &nbsp;//&nbsp;  <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments', '1 Comment ', '% Comments'); ?> 
                            </div>
                    <?php the_content(__('Read more >>')); ?>   
            </div>
            <!-- End .postBox -->
            <?php endwhile; ?>
                <!--<div class="navigation">
                            <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link() ?></div>
                            <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link() ?></div>
                </div>-->
                <?php if (function_exists("emm_paginate")) {
                    emm_paginate();
                } ?>
    
            </div>
            <!-- End #colLeft -->
    
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?> 
    <?php }?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Go to your static "Blog" Page and select the new template in page atributes.[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. However, im not sure how this solves the problem?  The new template file will still need tweaking to remove a category from it?  Why dont we just do this to the index.php?
Also where you tell me to add that php line, to me it looks like you have opened a php tag but not closed it?

Comment: @Simon I edited the answer and included the whole custom-page-blog.php template.  This template will show all the posts not in category 98.

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts here. You approach does look like it will work, however, Ashfame's answer does not require me to create a new template file, so would appear to be better?  Still testing...

Comment: His approach is great and much simpler.  Choose what works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to tell since you supplied no code but removing a category from your blog loop is typically very easy.

For instance above the main loop, if your category "portfolio" has an id=12 :

```
query_posts( 'cat=-12' );
```

Comment: Which php file will this be in?  Ive done a search for 'query_posts' in all PHP files in my theme and cant find it.

Comment: query_posts alters the "main loop" of your blog (usually index.php), you will have to add it yourself. http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: Thanks, been reading up on this.
Q1 - How do I find out what ID a category is? Do I need to dive into the database tables?
Q2 - My theme has its own index.php.  Still not too sure which line to place the query_posts in:
http://www.dekho.com.au/index.txt

Comment: The easiest way to find the category ID is to click your category in Admin and just hover over one and you will see the ID on mouseover or in your browser ( in Chrome it shows at bottom ).

Comment: Hi Wyck.  I found out that the category I want to exclude is 98, but I have not been able to fit it in the right place in my index.php file (see above link to see the code for this file)  Any ideas?

Comment: Your looking for this in your loop--> `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>` and you will need to add this directly above it `<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-98'); ?>`

Comment: Cheers.  It looks like my blog does not reference index.php.
http://www.dekho.com.au/blog/
However. my downloads page does:
http://www.dekho.com.au/category/downloads/
I am trying to remove the downloads from the main blog.  Adding that line into index.php just removes those blog posts from the downloads, but not the blog.

Comment: I don't know your theme, it could very well be in another page, sometime its called loop.php, have a look at some of the other files.

Comment: Would it make a difference that my blog is being shown on a 'static page' as opposed to the front page? (Reading settings)

Comment: I lie - my blog page does reference index.php, cos if I chage things like the text in the text below each post (author, date, etc) then it is reflected in my blog page.  Perhaps ive added that line in the wrong place?

Comment: See edits in orig Q

Comment: The code you inserted on line 2 belongs on line 29 in your index.php. Your downloads gallery uses the file portfolio.php

Comment: Nope.
Inserting <?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-98'); ?> onto line 29, above 
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
Still shows posts from the downloads category in my blog.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use something like [WordPress Download Monitor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-monitor/)?

Comment: Ill have a look at this.  Although still need my orig Q answered, as ill be using the portfolio template again for a category for Case Studies, so will still need to know how to exclude that category from the blog, and only the blog.

Comment: Im now using this for my downloads.  However, as per the edits in my Q, I am using the portfolio for my 'case studies'  Same problem persists where case studies show up in blog.

Answer (score 1):

if you use static page to show the blog post, add the wyck's code to template that used for that page.

Comment: I do use a static page, but I think it still uses index.php to populate items on this static page?  
I checked by fiddling some free text in index.php and it was reflected in the blog posts on the static page.