# Wordpress Website change directory

Tags: urls

I have wordPress site. My website works under demo directory. URL looks like this www.website.com/demo. I want change that to normal like www.website.com how to do that please help. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change URL for Blog?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/change-url-for-blog)

Comment: no dear, my full site stored under demo folder, u need to change to normal directory

Comment: if your site is stored under the /demo folder, you need to change the root directory of the server. Which http server and OS are you using?

Comment: how to charge root directory?

Answer (score 0):

Please change URL settings as given below:

WordPress Address (URL): www.website.com/demo

Site Address (URL): www.website.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to change url in database also,

```
https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/full/nzEjI
```

Go to this link and add you old url and new url. then copy the generated sql query and run that sql query in your database. This query change your old url to new url in all table.